# Autoupdate of primefaces component

Tags: ajax, jsf, refresh, onchange

What I have is this piece of xhtml Code:

```
 <p:layoutUnit id="bottomline" position="south" gutter="0">        
        <h:outputText rendered=",#{not empty sprintlisteMB.getSaveStatus()}" style="float:left; color:white; font-size: 0.8em;" value="#{sprintlisteMB.getSaveStatus()}"/>
 </p:layoutUnit>
```

`sprintlisteMB.getSaveStatus()` returns simply returns the String saveStatus. Now I want the outputText Component to refresh anytime saveStatus is changed.

I'm not quite sure how to implement something like that and i coudn't find anything that fits my needs.
Thanks for any help!

EDIT: 
So now i have Something like this:

```
<p:layoutUnit id="bottomline" position="south" gutter="0">
    <h:outputText style="float:left; color:white; font-size: 0.8em;"
        value="#{sprintlisteMB.getSaveStatus()}" />
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:socket onMessage="handleChange" channel="/saveStatus" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function handleChange(data) {
    $('.display').html(data);
}
```

...

```
 package de.wdr.testtool.helfer;

import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/saveStatus")
public class SaveStatusPushRecource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String onChange(String status) {
        return status;
    }
}
```

...

```
public void setSaveStatus(final String status) {
        saveStatus = status;

        final EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/saveStatus", String.valueOf(saveStatus));
    }
```

`setSaveStatus` is called from several beans anytime the changes on the database are made.
But right right now it still won't update the site. What's missing?

Comment: `h:outputText` is not a PrimeFaces component and `p:layoutUnit` is not relevant in this question, hence the question is **not** PrimeFaces related. And what you are looking for btw is called 'push' for which PrimeFaces does have a solution: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml

Comment: So I tried that...(see in EDIT)

Comment: _"the site still won't update"_ is what an end-user would describe. But what do you as a developer 'see'? What is the value of 'data' in the handleChange function? Is that correct? Then see if the element with the class 'display' exists and is found...

Comment: When I said it still won't update, I thought I just might have a pretty obvious mistake or just  forgotten something. Anyway, it actually seems the change was'nt even really applied. Because now, as soon as I implement the NotifyRecource, the local Server won't even start because of an AnnotationParserException